# How to change the playback speed of a clip in PS5’s media gallery, similar to what’s possible in PS4?

Tags: ps5

In PS4, whenever I view a clip I captured, I can fast forward or rewind by pressing either left/right or L2/R2, which would adjust the playback speed up to a maximum of 120x. However, in PS5, L2 and R2 don’t seem to have any effect, while left/right would always jump by 10 seconds. Is this to be expected? Feels like a massive regression to me since when jumping by intervals of 10 seconds, I can’t see exactly what was happening as the image is always frozen at the original frame, and I can’t locate a specific passage of play as a result. The 10 seconds interval is also too coarse I want to see for multiple times one specific play which finished in e.g. 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't any granular ways to forward / rewind video clips using the PS5 Media Player. The only option available is the +/- 10 second using the left / right arrows on the D-Pad, which you've mentioned.

However, when watching DVDs / Blu-ray movies, expanded controls are available, including 1.5x playback and up to 30x fast-forward.